# Why doesn't google maps display in a dynamically-generated div?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create embedded Google Maps elements dynamically. It works but not when the containing div has been created by `createElement`.

[Here is a full example.](http://pastebin.com/1xn1VR7h)

I am loading the Google Maps API dynamically

```
var s = document .createElement ('script');

s .src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" +
        "?key=" + GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY +
        "&callback=init_google_maps";

document .head .appendChild (s);

function init_google_maps ()
{
     ...
}
```

If I have this container

```
<div id="map" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:red"></div>
```

and the init code does this

```
var div = document .getElementById ('map');

var testmap = new google .maps .Map (div, ...);
```

then the map loads correctly.

However, if I do this

```
var div = document .getElementById ('map');

var subdiv = document .createElement ('div');

div .appendChild (subdiv);

var testmap = new google .maps .Map (subdiv, ...);
```

the map doesn't load. The javascript throws no exceptions and the inspector tells me there is stuff generated within `subdiv`, but it simply does not display anything.

Why would creating and using `subdiv` dynamically break the map?

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint as to why this is getting downvoted? Thanks.

Comment: testmapDiv should have CSS giving it height.  it should look like testmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("testmapDiv"), mapOptions);  also try 201px as 200px and below all cotrols are hidden i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the solution is:

- the div which is the map must have width and hight specified in CSS,
- be careful of percentage sizes, which don't work everywhere e.g. table cells,
- call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` after the map div has been placed in the DOM, visibly, and with width and height computed.

My full code re-childs the map div, which means all of the above must be reconsidered after the move.

Answer (score 0):

trigger the following after the load

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Comment: I tried that with map being either the containing div or the google.maps.Map object, and tried it immediately after creation and after a setTimeout. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` when your subdiv will be visible.

Like this

```
if($('#subdivid').css('display') == 'block')
{
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');                
}
```